# Get array data in for loop for chart using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, anychart

I have a for loop that gets data that I'm trying to parse into a chart. I can only seem to get the first bit of data, not everything in the array.

My JS file -

```
   for (i = 0; i < results; i++) {
       const assetName = await tronWeb.trx.getTokenByID(str.assetV2[i]['key']);
       var getAsset = JSON.stringify(assetName);
       var name = JSON.parse(getAsset);
       var assetValueRaw = str.assetV2[i]['value'] / 100;
       var assetValue = assetValueRaw.toLocaleString()

       // get chart data from for loop
       chartData = [name.abbr, assetValueRaw];
   }



   anychart.onDocumentReady(function () {

      // create pie chart with passed data from for loop
      var chart = anychart.pie([chartData]);

      var palette = anychart.palettes.rangeColors();
      palette.items([{ color: '#64b5f6' }, { color: '#455a64' }]);
      chart.background().fill("#222E3A 0.0");
      chart.height('100%');
      chart.width('100%');
      chart.padding(80);
      chart
         .innerRadius('95%')
         .palette(palette);
      chart.container('container');
    chart.draw();
  });
```

Example data:

```
chartData = [['test', 477], ['test2 ', 1000],];
```

The chart populates but there is supposed to be 3 values but only returns 1. How can I get the loop to push all 3 data values to the `chartData` variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reassigning a new array to `chartData` on each iteration, so it ends up with only the last value. Instead, you should create an empty array before the loop and `push` elements into it.

```
let chartData = [];
for (i = 0; i < results; i++) {
       const assetName = await tronWeb.trx.getTokenByID(str.assetV2[i]['key']);
       var getAsset = JSON.stringify(assetName);
       var name = JSON.parse(getAsset);
       var assetValueRaw = str.assetV2[i]['value'] / 100;
       var assetValue = assetValueRaw.toLocaleString()

       // get chart data from for loop
       chartData.push([name.abbr, assetValueRaw]);
   }
//...
var chart = anychart.pie(chartData);
```

Comment: Thank you, makes sense but Im not getting the chart now, I get the first valued displayed but I must be preparing the chartData wrong?

Comment: @RyanD What should the result look like?

Comment: chartData =  [['test', 477], ['test2 ', 1000], ['test3 ', 1000]];

Comment: @RyanD Try `anychart.pie(chartData);` (removed square brackets)